# trying to use lighttable with clojure offline - windows 7 w/o internet

Tags: windows, maven, clojure, offline, lighttable

LightTable seems to setup its own clojure lein and maven system to be a REPL.  The computer I am trying to use it on does not have internet access.  Is there a way for me to manually download the needed plugins and include them in light table created .m2 repository?

This is the error I get:

> We couldn't connect.
>
> Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's
> what we got:
>
> Could not transfer artifact lein-light:lein-light:pom:0.0.32 from/to
> central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection to
> http://repo1.maven.org refused Could not transfer artifact
> org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.5.1 from/to central
> (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org
> refused Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:tools.nrepl:pom:0.2.3
> from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection to
> http://repo1.maven.org refused Could not transfer artifact
> clojure-complete:clojure-complete:pom:0.2.3 from/to central
> (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org
> refused This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network
> issues.

LightTable was able to create empty directories in an .m2 directory in my user folder there.  It looks like its part of the way there and I'd just like to help it along a bit.

If it matters I do have leiningan installed and am able to use it, of course its only usable as a project maker/REPL starter.

---

#### [EDIT]

I've made a little bit of progress by copying over my .m2 folder from a working LightTable on another computer to the one on my windows computer.  Now I only have two error messages:

> We couldn't connect.
>
> Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's
> what we got:
>
> Could not transfer artifact lein-light:lein-light:pom:0.0.32 from/to
> central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/):
> Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused Could not transfer artifact
> org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.3.0 from/to central
> (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org
> refused This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network
> issues.

Any ideas as to how I can resolve these last two?  They are both clearly sitting in my .m2 folder with pom's and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Windows without internet now!  This is great for the protected environment I am forced to use - its also a great way for me to not worry about Maven.

A working setup is first needed, though.

1. So on another machine I load the clojure instarepl up and LightTable automatically puts all the JAR dependencies in a .m2 folder (Maven folder even though I don't even have Maven installed)
2. I copied the .m2/repositories folder from the machine with LightTable and internet over to the same folder on the 'protected' machine.
3. I had to completely remove LightTable and reinstall it for things to work after this.  Your mileage may vary.

Ultimately, I don't really know how to use Maven and am barely learning Clojure.  But at least now I can actually learn it.